# Roots over the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, unique-factorization-domains

Is it possible for a degree-5 polynomial over the complex numbers to have 1 as a root of multiplicity 1, *i* as a root of multiplicity 2, and no other roots?

I am trying to find an example where this is true. What I've come up with is

$(x-1)(x-i)^2$ but this has only degree 3. I cannot think of any examples over the complex numbers that make this statement true. I am thinking it is not a true statement. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: No, polynomials in the reals/complex numbers have a number of roots (including multiplicity) equal to their degree in the complex numbers. That is the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of algebra says a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots, counted by multiplicity.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you! Is this true for the rational numbers as well?

Comment: You mean rational roots? Or rational polynomials? Because rational polynomials are  real.

Comment: $\mathbb Q[x]\subset\mathbb C[x]$, so yes.

Comment: @DonThousand Over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Comment: As $\Bbb Q$ is not complete you can have fewer roots than the degree.  A polynomial that meets your question if the roots have to be rational is $(x-1)(x-i)^2(x^2-2)$  It has five roots in the complex numbers but two are irrational.

Comment: @RossMillikan So if I had a degree-5 polynomial over the rational numbers, would it be possible to have 1 as a root of multiplicity 2 and -1 as a root of multiplicity 3?

Comment: Sure, it would be $(x-1)^2(x+1)^3$.  If the coefficients are rational you can't have a single irrational root because the rationals are closed under multiplication and addition and Vieta's formulas relate the roots to the coefficients, but you can have two or more as $x^2-2$ shows.